# Laravel - Second User Registration Controller Method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What is the best method for create a custom user registration form, like a set of fields at the end of a cart, into the controller of another method (as in not the default Auth\RegistrationController? I'd like to just do it all in one just for the sake and ease of the user and myself.

I'd like the usual after registration events to happen, like the verification email, so I was hoping to get the best way of accomplishing as much as I can as close as I can to the original intent of user registration in Laravel.

Thanks!

Comment: you can override register method in Auth/RegsiterController and make it custom

Comment: You can just modify the `validator` and `create` method in the `RegisterController` and add your extra fields.